# Compare SQL Server Database Schema with Oracle Database Schema

Tags: sql-server, oracle, database-schema, rdbms

in my development environment we support the application both on MSSQL Server as well as Oracle. The database schema of both of these RDBMS are same.

while development we found that the developer made a mistake and forgot to change the oracle database for the last 1 yr. therfore the oracle script is quite behind in term of schema from SQL Server schema script.

now the question is how i can compare the two RDBMS systems to find the difference and make the oracle script updated

Comment: Compare the scripts from your **source code version control**.

Comment: @LalitKumarB the script is not in the correct order for both the database. means some objects are on top in one script and same objects are at the botton on the script. so just text comparision is not possible

Comment: I didn't say you need to do a text comparison. From your source control, you can easily find when and what were the changes done in the schema. You need to track all the changes and create one script which has the list of all the missed changes.

Answer (score 1):

If there are no track log from which it's possible to find and reproduce all changes applied to SQL Server since first detected inconsistency with Oracle version, or that changes was applied, but only partially, you really need to compare objects presented in both databases.
In this case setup a link between databases on any side and use system dictionary views to compare table structures and other objects to find differences and, possible, to generate script for Oracle scheme rollup.

If you want to act from MS SQL Server side:

1. [Install and configure Oracle Instant Client](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-100365.html)
2. [Install Oracle ODAC](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/utilsoft-087491.html)
3. [Follow Microsoft recomendations](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/280106) ([64-bit version](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dbrowne/archive/2013/10/02/creating-a-linked-server-for-oracle-in-64bit-sql-server.aspx))
4. Connect as any user with `dba` role (or use same Oracle schema where object resides) to Oracle from MS SQL database

If you want to act from Oracle Server side:

1. Install and configure [Oracle Database Gateway for SQL Server](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/gateways.111/b31043/sqlserver.htm#CCHEDECC).
2. [Create database link to MS SQL Server](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/gateways.111/b31043/conf_sql.htm#CIHEIIAB).

After successful configuration you may join [Information schema views](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778.aspx) on SQL Server side with [Data dictionary views](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/nav/catalog_views.htm) on Oracle side to find differences.

Of course there are many troubles at this way like [different data types](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/gateways.102/b14270/apa.htm), but it gives a chance to automate at least part of work.